# Shortest connect of vertices

Tags: python, scripting, objects

I have an object that is not connected, and want to make it connected by adding the shortest possible edges, i.e. by finding the closest pair of vertices that are not in the same connected component and add an edge between them, and repeat this.

I tried to make set1 of vertices with "select_linked" and set2 with the others, and then loop over all pairs of one from each set, explicitely calculating the distance, and saving the shortest one. That is very slow.

I tried numpy.linalg.norm. Even slower.

Then I found cdist in Scipy, which calculates all distances between two sets. Input must be ndarrays, not sets, so I must convert. Much quicker, but still too slow for larger objects. (OK for small objects, but I have one with 60.000 vertices, which seems completely impossible. My computer dies.)

Probably I should avoid the all-to-all loop. Any ideas?

The min distance should be very small, so I could skip all pairs that are too far apart, but I won't know this until I have calculated the distances. Right?

PS Any easy way to do profiling in python in Blender?

Comment: This seems more of a mathematical and algorithmic efficiency question ... perhaps Graph Theoretical..... rather than a Blender question.  A suggestion is to place your question in a Stack Exchange forum that addresses your concern more naturally.

Comment: Yes, that might be true, but I think that there are tools in Blender that might help very much.